# Как вывести перевод префикса цен?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_add_price_prefix', 99, 2 );

function bbloomer_add_price_prefix( $price, $product ){
    $prefix= do_shortcode("[:de]Ab[:en]From[:ru]От[:]"); 
    $price = $prefix . $price;
    return $price;
}
```

Мне нужно добавить префикс для цен.
Но сайт имеет несколько языков, поэтому нужно задать через шорткод несколько переводов.

Сейчас код выводит `[:de]Ab[:en]From[:ru] От[:]`,а не "From" например. Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: И что это за страшный шорткод?)

Comment: @WPPunk это от недоплагина мультиязычности типа WP Globus

Comment: @WPPunk  Плагин qTranslate-X

Comment: @KAGGDesign Подскажи пожалуйста, как мне добавить мультиязычный префикс цены?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
$prefix = __('[:de]Ab[:en]From[:ru]От[:]');
```